# Database design for apps using "hashtags"

Tags: mysql, normalization, hashtag

database design question here.

Say we had a webapp or something that uses hashtags for 20-40 word notes. What is the best way to store a user's hashtags.

For instance, if a user entered. `"I like to have #lunch at #sizzler"` we would store the sentence as text and we could store the hashtags as JSON, a comma separated list or some other mechanism.

Its also worth pointing out that the tags need to be searchable, such as how many people have been hash tagging lunch, etc.

Advise on the matter would be great, I always get a bit stumped when it comes to storing variable sized inputs in mysql. There can be an infinite number of hashtags per note, what is the best way to store them?

Comment: Not to beat a horse, but when rethinking this I noticed that you did not ask for mysql specifically in the question (and even mentioning csv and json...), might it be okay to tag this generally as "database" because it might open up interesting alternative nosql solutions or something else? .... (I was curious to compare a nosql to a relational solution and came back here, that is why I am asking :))

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I would advise going with a typical many-to-many-relationship between messages and tags.

That would mean you need 3 tables.

- `Messages` (columns `Id`, `UserId` and `Content`)
- `Tags` (columns `Id` and `TagName`)
- `TagMessageRelations` (columns: `MessageId` and `TagId` - to make the connections between messages and tags - via foreign keys pointing to `Messages.Id` / `Tags.Id`)

That way you do not store a tag multiple times but only create a new relation to a message (if that tag already exists in the tag-table of course).

This way you can

- easily **count how many tags** there are (`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tags`)
- **only save each tag once** and search for tags can be easily indexed
- or **count how many times a certain tag was used** per user - for example:

`SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    FROM Tags
    INNER JOIN TagMessageRelations ON Tags.Id = TagMessageRelations.TagId
    INNER JOIN Messages ON TagMessageRelations.MessageId = Messages.Id
    GROUP BY Messages.UserId`

Comment: Awesome, that was basically what I was thinking. Are tags unique in the tags table?

Comment: Yea, that is the idea, they are unique in the tags-table, but with multiple relationships in the tagMessagesRelation-table.

Comment: thx, glad I could help; ps: thx for the reminder, I am overdue for some ling slaying action :D

Comment: Why not using tag name as id? And possibly remove one table (to get all tags use distinct select). Is it really so much slower? At the end there will be name to id conversion anyway. And at the end there will be probably mem cache dictionary for all tags.

Comment: @StefanCebulak you could do that.
TLDR; I am pretty sure the additional amount of data (INT column) is insignificant to the other columns and should pay off in performance. 
Speedwise,I suppose you only would notice that once you have huge amounts of data in your database.
Did not test this myself, but it seems there is some evidence to suggest joining on ints is more efficient than joining on varchars (for example) following link is about sql server though: https://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/02/15/are-int-joins-faster-than-string-joins-2/

Comment: @StefanCebulak Sorry, I first only responded to the first part of your comment (just using tag-name as id), possibly removing one table (I assume you mean the tags-table itself leaving the tagrelations-table **denormalized** and that is really a waste of space (you would save the same possibly long tag-name multiple times) and also not wise for performance (string comparisons are not really cheap, see link in my previous comment)

Comment: How can we do that with NoSql database ? I thought I can put hashtags inside objects as an array attribute but when I want to search about the hashtags it won't work. Can you give any advice?

Comment: If you use tag value as PK (in a relational DB scenario) the bridge table will have values instead of ids which will be useful for a scenario such as get-all-tags-of-message. Maybe not ideal for tags-in-messages but good for other scenarios like Labels-in-articles.