# mySQL Error When Making Trigger To Find Hashtags and add them to other tables

Tags: mysql, triggers

The closest (it's exactly the same) thing I could find to what I'm doing is this...
[Database design for apps using "hashtags"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24799753/database-design-for-apps-using-hashtags)
...except that that question didn't address actually finding the hashtags, just how to store them, which doesn't help me with this, although it does makes me feel confident about my design choices.

I am trying to create a trigger, that every time a message is added it looks through to find hashtags and adds them to 2 other tables in my database.  One of the tables is 'hashTags' which is just a list of the tags & an ID column.  The other table is hashUsed, which shows where the hashtags are used with two columns (MsgID, HTagID) that are both set as PrimaryKey (shouldn't have a message & hashtag linked more than once).  I manually inserted some 'messages' with hashtags, I created the proper entries in the other tables to reference the data, and I've built queries that show the data just the way I need it.

I just can't figure out why this Trigger won't save.

When I execute it, I get this response:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version  for the right syntax to use near '@hl := INSTR(@s, '#'); /*get hashtag location*/  @ss := SUBSTRING(@s, @h' at line 14'

BTW... I'm using 'Toad for MySQL' which takes care of the delimiter automatically behind the scenes, which is why I don't have it here.

I added comments out the wazoo to help you follow along.
What did I do wrong?  Thanks in advance!

```
CREATE TRIGGER `mybase`.`FindHashTags` 
AFTER INSERT /* I chose AFTER INSER because I need to use the 
                auto_incremented 'MsgID' field/key, which doesn't 
                exist beforehand.  Correct me if I'm wrong. */
    ON mybase.messages FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN  
    DECLARE c INT; /* c stands for count */
    DECLARE h INT; /* h stands for HowMany times is the hashtag(#) present */

    SET @s := new.message; /* s stands for string */
    SET @h := (ROUND ((LENGTH(new.message) /* Get the Length of the Message */
          - LENGTH( REPLACE (new.message, "#", "") ) /* How long would the message be without the string in it*/
        ) / LENGTH("#"))); /*Divide the difference of those two lengths by the length of the string in question.  
                            This will tell how many times it was removed, hence how many times the string was 
                            present in the text. */

    SET @c := 1;
    WHILE @c <= @h DO
        @hl := INSTR(@s, '#'); /* get hashtag location */
        @ss := SUBSTRING(@s, @hl, LENGTH(@s)-@hl); /* Get all text after hashtag usint SubString*/
        @sl := INSTR(@ss,' '); /* String Length. Search the new substring for a space(' ') */
        IF @sl <= 0 THEN @sl=LENGTH(@S) /* If there isn't a space, set @sl position to end of the field */
          @ht := SUBSTRING(@ss, 1, @sl); /* @ht is a hashTag, select from first char to @sl */
          @s  := SUBSTRING(@ss, @sl, LENGTH(@SS)-@sl); /* remove the hashtag from the sting to prepare for searching 
                                                        again during next loop to look for more hashtags */
          INSERT IGNORE INTO hashTags(Name) VALUES (@ht); /* add hashtag to list, ignore if it already exists */
          @t  := (SELECT HTagID FROM hashTags WHERE Name=@ht); /* get the id of the hashtag we just found */
          INSERT IGNORE INTO hashUsed(MsgID,HTagID) VALUES (new.MsgID,@t); /* link the hashtag to the message */
          SET @c = @c + 1; 
        END IF
    END WHILE;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

1. I forgot to put SET in front of the variables in the WHILE block.

2. I also forgot the semicolon after END IF