# Best way to store hashtags and the uses / combinations in a database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, hashtag

So there is a huge collection of hashtags ( > 100.000 ) in a database.

Other functionality requires that the hashtags are stored in different tables ordered by the first letter ( tags_a, tags_b, ... ), but I think this fact can be ignored and be handled as one table for the solutions.

I now want to implement a counter for the uses of the tags.

So I think I could just apparent a column to these tables and have the corresponding value counted up each time the tag is used.

That way I would have to join the tables to e.g. get the top 100 used tags...

Is there a more clever and more performant and space saving way to save the counts ?

Also my other need is to store information about the combinations of tags that where used.

For example a user is using tags '#a, #e, #k, #w' and I want to have the information how often  #a was used together with #e & #a with #k & #e with #w and so on...

The first approach that comes in my mind would be a table with columns: tag 1 (FK), tag 2 (FK) and count, but this would be a table that is tag-count * tag-count long... isn't there a better way ?

In the future I would like to have a kind of recommendation like:

- You have used #e, you may also want to use #k.

( where #k is one of the most popular combination with #e )

Or something like a spam filter, where I check for possible / usual relations between tags.

How can I store this kind of information, again, in the most performant and space saving way ?

**EDIT**

I am expecting up to 1 million 'posts' per day, where each post can have up to 10 tags.

And actually these are not posts, but for simplicity, I will call them so.

The point is, that there will be a kind of AI implemented, that needs to read and learn from these and many other stored data, and also do other stuff, in a relatively short interval of time and we want to minimize the data to handle and process, as much as we can.

Comment: Did anyone actually do testing on the separate tables approach for all of your tags or was it just assumed that it was better. It looks like a lot of premature optimization going on here with way too much "cleverness" for its own good.

Comment: Actually this is just a theoretical question. All the requirements and conditions that I've mentioned are related to other functionallitys of that project that is going to be in the design state soon. Currently me and my team are brainstorming about possible solution attempts. So my question is for fundamental knowledge and to get a better overview of the base strukture of the current idea.

Comment: Also I should possibly mention that the reason for the performance optimization I am looking for is due to leak of our current development server capacity and processing power. And most importantly the system should be able to handle huge data that will be imported in the future, so we want to have a stable base from the beginning.

Comment: Storing in separate tables is almost always the wrong approach.  100,000 records is just not very big, and @TomH is right.

Comment: Well, I think we can ignore the splitted tables idea to find solutions for this question.

Comment: It feels like maybe, with the want for optimization, and the fact that you need counting and whatnot, that maybe a hybrid MySQL/Redis solution might be something to explore. Also, the separate table thing is just not a good idea. One table, indexed, will work much better than the Union query hell you are about to enter.

Comment: The question is more about how to realize all these countings. What kind of database / table strukture to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database design for apps using "hashtags"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24799753/database-design-for-apps-using-hashtags)

Answer (score 5):

I would start off with designing the database to match the real world requirements. You have hashtags, which are related to posts of some kind that are written by users. That sounds to me like a table for Users, a table for Posts (with an FK to Users), a table for Hashtags, and a many-to-many linking table between Posts and Hashtags with the appropriate FKs.

If you want to find how many times a hashtag has been used, then simply query the tables. Unless you're getting into the 10s of millions (possibly 100s of millions) of rows of data, then with proper indexing you should be fine.

Once you've implemented the basic functionality, if tests show (and not hunches) that you are going to run into performance issues then you can refine your requirements further to handle that problem.

Comment: That approath was one of the first thoughts that we had. We will also have to handle tons of tag usage, so we would like to only store data that we really need to store (in this case only the countings) and not have to make a new row entry for each usage. I've edited my question and mentioned a table for each pair of tags with a counter.

Comment: Maintaining calculated data in a database is a mistake more often than it is not. Also, if you want to store all of the distinct pairs of hashtags then you now have 100,000 choose 2 = 100,000 * 99,999/2 possible combinations or 4,999,950,000 combinations. It's also unclear what extra data you'll be storing. Are you not already going to be tying hashtags to the posts, etc. to which they belong or are those just being tossed out? Either way, I don't think there's much more that I can offer here.

Comment: @Ace - what do you mean by "tons of tag usage"? Do you have a number?

Comment: I think you where meaning to say 'calculatABLE data'. And yes you are right, the possible combinations table would be huge, but not if I only save the pairs of tags that have actually been used. At this point, I also don't need to store any other data related to the tags.

Comment: @Paul - I am expecting more than 1 million 'posts' per day, where each post can have up to 10 tags. And actually these are not posts, but a similar type of data that has to do with internal company processes.

Comment: @Ace - You might want to add that info to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the main question is "How do bump counters hundred(s) of times per second?"

If you have SSD drive(s), simply do `UPDATE ... SET x = x + 1 WHERE ...`.  If not, you will bottleneck on disk activity.  (Also, thousands may overwhelm SSDs.)

It would be nice if you could build that `UPDATE` with `WHERE hashtag IN (the-10-or-so-hashtags)`.  (Your choice to split the data into multiple tables essentially prevents this optimization.)  But there is hope -- the counters *really should* be in a table of their own, *not* in the main table of users.  This is to segregate the high activity of the counters from other uses.

So, you need to buffer up the hashtags and update them in batches.  This might delay the counting a little, but that is better than swamping the system.

Will the info come in from one thread?  Multiple threads, but one server?  Multiple threads?  The details of the solution depend on the answers to those questions (and probably other questions).  Meanwhile, read [my blog on high speed ingestion](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table) for some hints on the direction I will take you.