# How to create tags in firestore?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I`m writing an android app and using Firestore to store data.

How to create tags like Twitter and Instagram? For example when user want to post a picture, the user select tags like #today.

Also how to search for the pictures posted in that tag?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is going to be too broad a question.  I'm imaging your storing your image somewhere (maybe GCS) and that you have a link to your image.  Your metadata (tags) will likely be stored in a database and likely used as keys.  The record/document associated with the tag will be a list/set of links to the images.  However, that is just one possible design and there are many others.

Comment: Hi @andr111, I think that you might take a look in a future, how this information would be helpful for you, to build information from the data. There are some docs that might be of your interest: [Build Your Own Instagram Database](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-your-own-instagram-database-134281e8ee92), [this is a similar question(DB Relational)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24799753/database-design-for-apps-using-hashtags). Just as Kolban said, there is not a single way to achieve this, I think you might focus on your final solution and goals for this.